# How to decrypt raw tcp data?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I am trying to decode TCP data from an application, I know the data is not encrypted but a clue suggested that "manipulating the bytes and bits" does the work, I can't figure it out myself.

The raw TCP data is: `8b5d002e7e5200048f100040`

Hex Dump:

```
00000000  8b 5d 00 2e 7e 52 00 04  8f 10 00 40               .]..~R.. ...@
```

CArray:

```
char peer1_0[] = { /* Packet 51 */
0x8b, 0x5d, 0x00, 0x2e, 0x7e, 0x52, 0x00, 0x04, 
0x8f, 0x10, 0x00, 0x40 };
```

Here is the Hex dump for the entire packet, maybe there is something that I am missing?

```
0000   0c 9d 92 11 14 f5 e0 ce c3 89 f6 6a 08 00 45 00   ...........j..E.
0010   00 34 79 62 40 00 6f 06 0a d6 c7 e5 fd ee c0 a8   .4yb@.o.........
0020   01 0f 59 d9 f9 7a 64 6a c5 50 70 48 f0 65 50 18   ..Y..zdj.PpH.eP.
0030   7f 62 31 e2 00 00 8b 5d 00 2e 7e 52 00 04 8f 10   .b1....]..~R....
0040   00 40                           .@
```

Comment: hash (md5, sha1, ...)?

Comment: What do you mean? @ChristopherMaynard

Comment: Maybe try https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/?

Comment: What do you expect from this? Maybe this data is meaningful for that application although doesn't have any meaning for you. And this payload may be analyzed with other packets.